# Swift - Get frames of view when auto layout is used

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, frame

In my view that is used as a sub view in a view controller, I defined differents components using auto layout. However, within my sub view, I need to access the frames of the components.

Here is my code:

```
class CreateChallengeView: AbstractCreateChallengeOrTournamentView {
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
    
      setupView(frame: frame)
  }

 private func setupView(frame:CGRect) {

     setNeedsLayout()

    /* START SCROLL VIEW */
    scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(scrollView)
    
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: frame.width * (22 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH)).isActive = true
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width * (331 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH)).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    /* END SCROLL VIEW */
    
    /* START CONTAINER VIEW */
    containerView = UIView()
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    containerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    containerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    /* END CONTAINER VIEW */
    
    /* START TITLE LABEL*/
    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.containerView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    
    titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: frame.height * (19 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true
    titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width * (284 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH)).isActive = true
    titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerView.topAnchor, constant: frame.height * (11 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true
    titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.height * (27 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true
    titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(CHALLENGE_NAME_TEXT, comment: "")
    print(titleLabel.frame) --> (0,0,0,0) How to get frame?
    /* END TITLE LABEL */
```

How do I get the frames directly of my **titleLabel** as an example?

Answer (score 2):

You do not know the results of autolayout except in `layoutSubviews`. So override it, call super, and now you can do things that depend on a knowledge of the frames.

Comment: In general, however, if you need to know any frames while using autolayout, you are doing autolayout wrong.

Comment: Thanks @matt.

     `let firstLineLayer = UIViewUtil.drawLine(startingPointX: 0, endingPointX: 
          frame.maxX, startingPointY: descriptionTextView.frame.maxY + 20, 
         endingPointY:455)
        firstLineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        containerView.layer.addSublayer(firstLineLayer)`

 need to access the maxY of each component to show a horizontal line after the particular view. Only for that, I need to the frame since I can't use auto layout on CAShapeLayer

Comment: No but you can use it on a view that hosts a shape layer.

Comment: Good point. Let me try it!

Comment: Works! Genius :) Thanks